# Create an apk that's a slideshow of images? (Android)

Tags: android, android-development

Non-developer UI / UX designer here.  Looking at ways to show android prototypes on some dev tablets that are locked down. Locked down in a sense that they can't get to android market they only have access to their own suite of apps but new apps can be loaded to their system for testing. So a loadable apk is really the only way to do this.

The ways that I'm interested in pursuing are from a set of a number of images, creating an APK that is essentially a slideshow of those images, press to proceed, slide to proceed, doesn't matter all that much.  And aside from that, wrapping an HTML clickable prototype (again could be images with image map hot spots) that could be generated into an APK.

Anyone know of an existing utility or easy method for a non-developer to work from? I've been doing a little research on the various drag drop builders, like app inventor but so far nothing has clicked as far as a method or process.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to get apk file of some slide show app and install it on tablet, but if making app is only solution, here is some help.

You could try Sketchware app on Play Store, but if that does not work you will have to make it on you own. It is not hard to do, here is list of some things i think you wil need look for on net to make it.

1.ImageView

Next thing are in java and android so make sure you search from this in java and android or you will end up with solution for other languages

2.OnClickListener (implement it on ImageView just like you wolud on normal button, it will work

3.if, else if, else (to switch between images)

4.int (to hold the number of current image)

5. Also look for "[how to change image in ImageView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089300/how-can-i-change-the-image-of-an-imageview)"

Here is an idea how it could work:

1.When app is started ImageView is set to show image 1
2.OnClickListener is seted on ImageView (you don't have to set listener again after every click, once set it will react every time ImageView is clicked).
3.Int is created to hold number of current image and is set to 1
4.Every time user clicks ImageView if int is bigger than number of images it is reseted to 1 else it is incerased by 1. ImageView is set specific picture using if and else if.

Happy coding :)

Add a comment if you have more questions